# Tradução de "questions with no upvoted or accepted answers"

Tags: debate, bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

Na lista "Sem resposta" aparece "perguntas sem resposta aceita nem com voto a favor", mas penso que "resposta aceita" deveria ser "resposta aceite".

(Há algum sítio melhor para discutir isto?)

Comment: Bem visto. Sim, este é o sitio certo para discutir isso. Para mim que falo português de Portugal a versão atual é errada e a tua sugestão é correta.

Comment: @Sergio acho que é uma questão de pt-PT e pt-BR

Comment: No Brasil, não é comum usar aceit**e** e sim aceit**a** ou aceit**o** (dependendo do gênero).

Comment: Também me parecia que sim @emanuelsn...

Comment: @emanuelsn "o candidato foi aceito para as eleições" e "a candidata foi aceita para as eleições" usa-se? Aqui usa-se aceita para "Jorge aceita esta prenda como uma gratificação pelo teu trabalho" e "Eu aceito este contrato que me propuseram" nos casos acima usamos aceite.

Comment: *"o candidato foi aceito para as eleições"* e *"a candidata foi aceita para as eleições"*.  A palavra "aceito" e "aceita" se referem, respectivamente ao candidato e a candidata.  Então, da forma como as frases foram escritas, está correto, @JorgeB.. Já a outra frase que você citou, "aceita esta prenda como uma gratificação pelo teu trabalho", acho válido usar a palavra aceit**e**, uma vez que o aceite, se refere a prenda e "prenda" é invariável (não existe *o prenda*. Será sempre *a prenda*).

Comment: @emanuelsn não é o caso de ser correto ou não aqui diz-se sempre aceite "o candidato foi aceite para as eleições" e "a candidata foi aceite para as eleições". Aceito só usamos no caso de ser na primeira pessoa do singular "Eu aceito este trabalho". Aceita é usado quando nos referimos a terceira pessoa do singular "Jorge aceita este trabalho que não arranjas outro igual".

Comment: @JorgeB. Eu disse "correto" no sentido de ser a forma que usamos aqui no Brasil. Confesso que não foi uma boa escolha. Desculpe se passou a impressão de dizer que outra forma é errada.

Comment: Não vejo nenhuma forma de "agradar" PTs e BRs nesse caso.

Comment: Uma rápida pesquisa na internet sugere que ambas formas estão gramaticalmente corretas. Nesse caso não sei qual é o procedimento padrão do SO. [Link 1](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-aceitar) [Link 2](http://pt.bab.la/verbo/portugues/aceitar)

Answer (score 2):

Na minha opinião, em "*resposta aceita*", "*candidato aceito*" e "*candidata aceita*", o "*aceito*"/"*aceita*" é um adjetivo e está em concordância nominal com o gênero do substantivo, e portanto está correto. O problema é que embora esteja correto, isso soa estranho em Portugal.

Por outro lado, "*aceite*" também é neste contexto um adjetivo com a mesma finalidade e independente de gênero, mas soa muito estranho no Brasil.

Já em "*Jorge aceita a prenda*", o "*aceita*" é a forma singular da terceira pessoa do modo indicativo do verbo "*aceitar*", o que é diferente de "*Jorge, aceite a prenda*", aonde "*aceite*" é uma das formas do singular da segunda pessoa do modo imperativo do verbo "*aceitar*". A outra forma do singular da segunda pessoa do modo imperativo seria "*Jorge, aceita a prenda*". Neste caso, a vírgula faz toda a diferença. Entretanto, em hipótese nenhuma o "*aceite*" poderia ser conjugado como se estivesse no modo indicativo.

E por sinal, a proposta da comunidade de língua portuguesa na Area 51 seria bem interessante para esse tipo de dúvida, e já está em 91% da fase de *commitment* neste momento. Convido a todos fazerem o commit lá:

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Portuguese Language]